# i need to configure file path to a remote server,i need web.config settings to do this with ftp credentials

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

i need to configure file path to a remote server,i need web.config settings to do this with ftp credentials
iam trying to upload the files to remote server other than application server

only one chance i have i.e FTP

can you plz guide me

Answer (score 0):

Actually iam seeing for web.config settings to configure ftp credentials in web.config as i have added a key for folder location in web.config